# Establishing connection from SQL Server to Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, tcp

I enabled my TCP/IP protocol but it is still giving me an error on my eclipse id saying that the connection to host has failed. I restart my SQL Server after enabling my TCP/IP but no luck.
Here is my code, I just want to establish connection.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class Driver {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String connectionString=
                "jdbc:sqlserver://csci331-server;Database=TSQLV4;IntegratedSecurity=true";
        try {
            try(Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)){
                System.out.println("Connection Established");
            }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error conncetion to the database");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE, you don't connect to it; it's like asking how to connect from C# to Visual Studio or Python to Notepad++. It's SQL Server that is the RDBMS.

Comment: Don't just print the stack trace.  The SQLException has useful error information in it.  Get that error information and add it to your question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/handling-errors?view=sql-server-ver15